# Placing a responsive square in a flex column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a game website where there is a header, a chessboard, and footer. I need to fit all three within the view port. The chessboard should shrink to make this happen.

The shrinking is what I'm having a problem with. I have been able to get width responsiveness, but not to a restrictive height.

The chessboard should remain square and take up unused space or shrink to prevent overflow.

I am doing something along the lines of the following, but the chessboard ends up overflowing the height of the parent.

In my actual code, the height of the header is unknown because of wrapping. The footer has variable amounts of text. Inside the chessboard is a a series of divs representing rows and a series of children representing the individual squares of the chessboard. The squares have aspect-ratio on them

```css
.parent {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  height: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.child {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.chessboard {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  background-color: purple;
  margin: auto;
}

.footer {
  height: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="header">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="chessboard">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: 1) What is inside `.chessboard`?
2) Is the height of the `.header` and `.footer` known?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final answer depends on some clarifications on your part. I asked you in a comment to the question. But I will give a universal answer.

I will briefly explain what is done in the example below.
I created a `.chessboard-wrapper` that has a `<canvas>` in it. `<canvas>` scales as you need and has `aspect-ratio: 1;`.
The `.chessboard` itself has `position: absolute;` and will take the dimensions of the father.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  height: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  flex: none;
}

.child {
  background-color: red;
  flex: auto;
  min-height: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.chessboard-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 0;
  margin: auto;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
}

.chessboard-wrapper > canvas {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.chessboard {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background-color: purple;
}

.footer {
  height: 10px;
  background-color: green;
  flex: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="chessboard-wrapper">
      <canvas width="1000000" height="1000000"></canvas>
      <div class="chessboard"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you say more about why you include the canvas to influence the father dimensions? Why not put canvas's properties on .chessboard itself?

Comment: @dgrogan If `.chessboard` is a `<canvas>` element, then you can simply replace `.chessboard` with `<canvas>`. That is why I asked clarifying questions. But, unfortunately, the author did not answer. So I made a universal solution where `.chessboard` is not a `<canvas>` element...

Comment: Why use canvas at all though? Why is `<canvas>` necessary?

Comment: Because `<canvas>` keeps the proportions. You can also use `<img>`, but without the specified `src` - it will be invalid. And with `src` - it will break (find the answer yourself why). Also breaks if you try to use `<div>` for example.

Comment: I updated my answer with more information.

Comment: I have given you a universal answer that can be a starting point in solving your task.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have accepted your answer. My apologies for the delay.

Answer (score 0):

You have `aspect-ratio` that say to the chessboard to have the same height as width, so if your width is 3000px your height will be the same. You have options

1. remove the aspect ratio
2. with my example, remove the child wrapper element
3. set a max-height to the chessboard

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.child {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: lightcoral;
}

.chessboard {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  background-color: purple;
  margin: auto;
}

.footer {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <header class="header">
  </header>

  <div class="child">
    <div class="chessboard">
      main
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer class="footer">
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: The chessboard needs to remain square. In the example you've given it's stretched out into a wide rectangle.

Comment: @hackpoetic you need to set a max width on the chessboard then, so my option #3. Let me update the answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a grid with the board in the middle.
I gave the "child" a different color just to show it was there. Notice how the board stays inside of that but the markup forces us to add an aspect ratio to it also.

EDIT: to let the padding to the heavy lifting here.  A lot of credit to this idea here: https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratios-grid-items/#aa-scenario-1-just-the-element-inside-needs-to-have-an-aspect-ratio

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.parent {
  background-color: grey;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 5% 1fr 5%;
  /* calc middle row based on other two */
  grid-template-rows: 0.625em calc(100vh - 1.35em) 0.625em;
}

.grid>* {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  place-items: start;
}

.grid>[style^='--aspect-ratio']::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1px;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: calc(100% / (var(--aspect-ratio)));
}

.header,
.footer {
  grid-column: span 3;
}

.header {
  grid-row: 1;
  background-color: #0000FF;
}

.footer {
  grid-row: 3;
  background-color: #008000;
}

.child {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
  background-color: #E6E6FA;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  /* just to show the board stays inside it */
  padding-top: 0.25em;
}

.chessboard {
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  background-color: #800080;
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="parent grid">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="child" style="--aspect-ratio: 1/1;">
    <div class="chessboard"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. However this appears to only be partially responsive. I am interested in the square becoming smaller if the height of the parent becomes more confining.

Comment: I put in an update due to the markup of the board in the child;  I think this gets you close but you may want to clamp to some minimal size.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work if you reduce the width of the screen (a square will not be a square). Also, it seems like you don't understand the code you wrote... Regards.

Comment: Or at least put some text in the `.header` or `.footer` and see what happens.

Comment: The original post had no text in the header or footer so this does not either - perhaps not as well asked as could be.

Comment: My apologies for my low quality post. I've updated it with more details from the actual project.